# How to change React Appbar links from purple

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React web app where my Appbar options have links associated with them, which underlined and turned the font purple. I also have a scroll function that changes the text color to black once I have scrolled down from the top position on the page.

I can't figure out how to make the text color white, while keeping the color change functionality on change.

**Header**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppBar, IconButton, Toolbar, Collapse } from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { Link as Scroll } from 'react-scroll';
import ScrollToColor from './ColorChangeOnScroll';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
  },
  appbar: {
    position: 'fixed',
    zIndex: '9999',
    background: 'black',
  },
  appbarTitle: {
    flexGrow: '1',
    fontSize: '1vw',
  },
  appbarTitle2: {
    flexGrow: '1',
    fontSize: '1vw',
  },
  appbarWrapper: {
    width: '80%',
    margin: '0 auto',
  },
  icon: {
    color: '#2bbcd4',
    fontSize: '2vw',
  },
  colorText: {
    color: '#2bbcd4',
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 30,
    background: '#2bbcd4',
  },
  buttontext: {
    fontFamily: 'Nunito',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  rightToolbar: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: -12,
    display: 'flex',
  },
}));

export default function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <section>
      <div className={classes.root} id="header">
        <ScrollToColor>
          <AppBar className={classes.appbar} elevation={0}>
            <Toolbar className={classes.appbarWrapper}>
              <a
                href="/landing"
              >
                <h1 className={classes.appbarTitle}>
                  Logo{' '}
                </h1>
              </a>
              <section className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                <a
                  href="/contact"
                >
                  <h2
                    className={classes.appbarTitle2}
                  >
                    Contact Sales
                  </h2>
                </a>
                <a
                  href="/login"
                >
                  <h2
                    className={classes.appbarTitle2}
                    style={{ marginRight: '50px' }}
                  >
                    Sign In
                  </h2>
                </a>
                <Button
                  className={classes.button}
                  size="large"
                  variant="contained"
                  href="/signup"
                  style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}
                >
                  <span className={classes.buttontext}>
                    Get started for free{' '}
                  </span>
                </Button>
              </section>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
        </ScrollToColor>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

**Scroll to change font color function:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useScrollTrigger } from "@material-ui/core";

const ScrollHandler = props => {
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0,
    target: props.window ? window() : undefined
  });

  return React.cloneElement(props.children, {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: trigger ? "white" : "transparent",
      color: trigger ? "black" : "white",
      transition: trigger ? "0.3s" : "0.5s",
      boxShadow: trigger ? "1px 1px 1px #efefef" : "none",
      padding: "10px 0px",
      icon: trigger ? "black" : "white",
    }
  });
};

const ScrollToColor01 = props => {
  return <ScrollHandler {...props}>{props.children}</ScrollHandler>;
};

export default ScrollToColor01;
```

I have tried adding inline styling to the text/links, and they do turn the font white & remove the underline, but it prevents the scroll function from working and as I scroll down, the text remains white (and invisible in front of a white background).

```
                <a
                  href="/login"
                  style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white' }}
                >
                  <h2
                    className={classes.appbarTitle2}
                    style={{ marginRight: '50px' }}
                  >
                    Sign In
                  </h2>
                </a>
```

Any advice on how to change the font color from purple to white and keep the scroll color functionaility is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a wrapper for the `anchors` and change the color of the wrapper instead on your scroll functionality, while setting the `color` of the anchors to `inherit`. This way the anchors will always inherit the color you set on the wrapper, even when visited.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ...

  links: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: 'inherit'
  },

  ...

}));
```

And then for the links you simply add the class:

```
<a href="/contact" className={classes.links}>
  <h2 className={classes.appbarTitle2}>Sales</h2>
</a>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @John, do you mind showing me what that looks like in a brief code snippet? Are you suggesting I change ```color: trigger ? "black" : "white",``` to  ```color: "inherit"``` in my scroll functionality file's ```style```?

Comment: Sure @Henrik, I edited my answer. After giving it a second look, I don't think you need to wrap your anchors, since you're already setting the styles to the AppBar, so a simple `inherit` on the anchors would suffice.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!